# Ruby 1.8.7: Symbol not found Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, symbols, memprof

Just did a fresh install of ruby 1.8.7 REE and MRI on a machine with fresh gem sets (Using RVM) Yet in each of them when I try to use memprof i get this error

```
$ gem install memprof
$ irb
>> require 'rubygems'
>> require 'memprof'
>> LoadError: dlopen(/Users/schneems/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@test/gems/memprof-0.3.10/lib/memprof.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: __mh_bundle_header
  Referenced from: /Users/schneems/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@test/gems/memprof-0.3.10/lib/memprof.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/schneems/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@test/gems/memprof-0.3.10/lib/memprof.bundle - /Users/schneems/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@test/gems/memprof-0.3.10/lib/memprof.bundle
    from /Users/schneems/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@test/gems/memprof-0.3.10/lib/memprof.bundle
    from /Users/schneems/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from (irb):2
```

The error is `Symbol not found: __mh_bundle_header`. My question is this: what do i need to do to get my system to find this symbol, or is there something else I need to install? Any debugging suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Yay for the ambiguous tag [symbol].

Comment: I've posted a meta question about the tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110399/how-should-the-symbols-tags-be-split-up

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did to get it to work on Snow Leopard:

`cd ..../gems/memprof-0.3.10/ext/`

Edit Makefile, search for LD_SHARED=

Change from

`LDSHARED = cc -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace`

to

`LDSHARED = cc -arch x86_64 -bundle -bundle_loader $(RUBY) -undefined suppress -flat_namespace`

(replaced -dynamiclib with -bundle and -bundleloader options)

Then,

`make install`  (which creates memprof.bundle and copies it to memprof*/lib)

Edit:  Just to clarify, `$(RUBY)` must contain the full pathname to the ruby interpreter (the executable). Under RVM, the Makefile initializes it to the appropriate interpreter, so the above line works without a problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'll try it out as soon as i get a chance. What exactly is the change above doing?

Comment: -bundle creates a bundle, a mac-specific dynamic library format. The memprof bundle has references to symbols in the host program, the ruby interpreter. The -bundle_loader option points to the particular executable that is going to load this bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was not compiled correctly and was missing the linker flags for the bundle library.  Try building it was `LDFLAGS="-bundle"`... I'm not sure how you do that with RVM, but I assume it will inherit the environment you give it.

EDIT | Sorry, looks like the correct ld flag may be: `LDFLAGS="-bundler_loader"`
EDIT 2 | Actually, I'm not sure if it's `bundle` or `bundle_loader`... I'm seeing both in Google results.

Comment: I tried using `rvm export` with both flags and i'm still getting the error. Maybe thats not the right command?

Comment: `rvm export` seems to be for managing gemsets, not for changing compile settings.  First try removing memprof, then do `LDFLAGS="-bundle" gem install memprof`, and if that doesn't work, try building ruby the same way (with LDFLAGS set)... it's not clear from the backtrace which is trying to use bundle.  I think it's actually ruby when trying to load the gem itself.

Comment: tried `LDFLAGS="-bundle" gem install memprof` and also `LDFLAGS="-bundle" rvm install 1.8.7` and neither worked.